# How do I set POST Parameters in a TestHttpClient

Tags: groovy, spock, ratpack

I'm using Ratpack's [TestHttpClient](https://ratpack.io/manual/current/api/ratpack/test/http/TestHttpClient.html) to send a `POST` request in a Spock test for a REST API. The API's endpoint accepts the parameter `myPostParam` as part of the request body / POST parameter.

I see that there is a `post` method, that performs the POST request, but I don't know how I can send the parameter `myPostParam=123456`

```
import ratpack.groovy.test.GroovyRatpackMainApplicationUnderTest
import ratpack.test.http.TestHttpClient
import ratpack.test.ServerBackedApplicationUnderTest
import spock.lang.Specification

class MyApiSpecification extends Specification {

  ServerBackedApplicationUnderTest aut = new GroovyRatpackMainApplicationUnderTest()
  @Delegate
  TestHttpClient client = testHttpClient(aut)

  def "Doing a API call for Stackoverflow"() {
    given:
    int myPostParam = 123456

    when:
    post("/api/v1.0/someMethod/")
    // TODO: How do I add "myPostParam=$myPostParam" to the request body?

    then:
    response.statusCode == 201
    response.body.text.empty
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`TestHttpClient.params(action)`](https://ratpack.io/manual/current/api/ratpack/test/http/TestHttpClient.html#params-ratpack.func.Action-) to set request parameters. Something like this should do the trick:

```groovy
import ratpack.groovy.test.GroovyRatpackMainApplicationUnderTest
import ratpack.test.http.TestHttpClient
import ratpack.test.ServerBackedApplicationUnderTest
import spock.lang.Specification

class MyApiSpecification extends Specification {

  ServerBackedApplicationUnderTest aut = new GroovyRatpackMainApplicationUnderTest()
  @Delegate
  TestHttpClient client = testHttpClient(aut)

  def "Doing a API call for Stackoverflow"() {
    given:
    int myPostParam = 123456

    when:
    params({ params ->
      params.put("myPostParam", myPostParam)
    }).post("/api/v1.0/someMethod/")

    then:
    response.statusCode == 201
    response.body.text.empty
  }
}
```

Comment: I had difficulties understanding how to use `params()` and thought it was only for internal use. But your example works wonderful. Thanks!